# Why doesn't Kotlin apply optimisations like .toSet() by itself?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, optimization

When I have

```
val orphans = mutableSetOf<Builds>()
val allBuilds: List<Builds> = ... more than just a one-liner
val classifiedBuilds: List<Builds> = category1 + category2 + category3
```

and I try

```
orphans.addAll(allBuilds - classifiedBuilds)
```

then IntelliJ recommends putting `.toSet()` on the end of `classifiedBuilds` as a performance optimisation.

- I'm curious why Kotlin doesn't do that for itself.
- I'm concerned that this is cruft that might not be optimal in a later version of Kotlin.

I could understand if IntelliJ is actually suggesting that I change my algorithm to make `classifiedBuilds` a set from the very start (which I can't do because I'm also using it to compute if builds have been classified into multiple categories), but it seems odd (and unhappily Ruby-like) that the Kotlin interface doesn't have an overload for `addAll(List<>)` to apply the `.toSet()` internally, so I'm forced to pepper my code with random magic 'optimisations' that work in the current Kotlin, but could be pessimisations in a later version.

Comment: The automatic internal conversion to a Set of the argument to _minus_ (and _intersect_ and others) was revoked in Kotlin 1.6. See this discussion on why this was done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45438

Comment: @lukas.j Thanks for this. If you make it an answer, I'll be able to mark it correct.